# Is soap foam better for cleaning than soapy water?

Tags: chemistry, water, cleaning

Most people who wash something using soap (e.g. the dishes), seem to believe that the bubbles contribute a great deal in the actual cleaning. This is not something I explicitly saw written down somewhere, but looking at how people (including me) clean with soap, it would seem that this is a very common belief.

So is the bubbly part (the foam) actually important when cleaning? Or would my plates come out just as clean when I completely submerge them the whilst washing?

Comment: I've never heard anyone who believed that. Can we find some users who believe that, or someone who has written it down, so we know it is notable and not just one perwson's speculation?

Comment: Actually I notice people doing this all the time. They focus on the part of the cleaning water which carries the bubbles. As I said I did not see it explicitly written down somewhere, so I knew it would be a long shot for this question to be on-topic.

Comment: @gebruiker I know what you mean, but I'm also not finding anyone claiming this. It's hard to separate from the idea "soap causes bubbles, so if there are bubbles, that means there's enough soap", which is a much more trivial claim. Can find plenty of soap products that claim to both clean, and to form bubbles (foaming dish soap is a thing, too), but I haven't found any of them claiming what you're saying. [Ultrasonic cleaners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasonic_cleaning) use cavitation bubbles for cleaning, sometimes without needing any soap, but I think that's different.

Comment: I've always believed this... I told a friend emphatically once, and have felt a little bad ever since because I was and still am not sure it's actually true.